# Show And Hidden Block After refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to keep the state of a hidden block after a page refresh.
When i refresh my page the block "hidden" is "show" now.
Help me please.

Comment: Can you post a code sample please? It is hard to figure out what's broken without it.

Comment: can you post the code please

Comment: Have you thought about using a cookie or local/session storage?

Comment: Definitely a job for a cookie (monster).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest passing a the "hidden" value (true/false) back to the server when you do a refresh, and then assigning it each time the page is loaded (don't forget to set a default value for first visit).

If you post a code sample or tell me what technology your using (e.g. .NET,MVC3), I could give you some sample code or resources to get you started on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

This does require the [CSS3 :target](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_target.asp) pseudo selector but it may be a viable solution:

**CSS:**

```
#myblock {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:#3a6d90;
    display:none; // div starts out as hidden
}

#myblock:target {
    display:block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href='javascript:showBlock();'>Show It</a>
<div id='myblock'></div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
function showBlock() {
    document.getElementById('myblock').style.display = "block";
    window.location.hash = "myblock"; // set url hash
}
```

The solution works by adding a URL hash to the current address when the element is displayed via `showBlock()` . The `#myblock:target` does the magic by setting the display property to 'block' when the #myblock hash is present